# Как добавить класс элементу в случае успешного срабатывания ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть элемент, по клику на сервер уходит запрос, в случае, если с сервера приходит ответ, этому элементу должен прислониться класс.
пробовал вот так:

```
 $(this).addClass('active');
```

но ничего не происходит, подскажите как все таки прицепиться к текущему элементу но после срабатывания ajax?

```js
$('.cal-month tbody td.cal-av').click(function(el) {
  d = $(this).text();
  m = $(this).parents('.cal-month').data('cal-month');
  y = $(this).parents('.cal-month').data('cal-year');
  today = y + '-' + m + '-' + d;
  nid = $(this).parents('.node-ntcnjdsq-vfnthbfk').find('.field-name-nid .field-item').text();
  var string = "nid=" + nid + "&today=" + today;
  $.ajax({
    url: '/qqq',
    type: 'POST',
    data: string,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      $(this).addClass('active');//вот так не работает((

    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this` в callback не относится к селектору, можете сделать так

```
$('.cal-month tbody td.cal-av').click(function(el) {
var button = $(this);
.......

success: function(result) {
      button.addClass('active');

    }
```

Comment: Дополню: в ajax запросе this будет ссылаться на сам объект который выполняет запрос и принимает ответ. Дело в том, что в JQ  `$.ajax` это всего лишь обертка над объектом `XMLHttpRequest`, кторый создается с помощью ключевого слова `new` соответственно  `this` в нем будет ссылаться экземпляр класса `XMLHttpRequest` и как посоветовал автор ответа, нужно сохранить объект события в переменную.